# Query to pull data from mysqli table

Tags: php, mysql

I created a database of users, posts and friends and want to pull all post from posts where account_name is $u = "logged in user" and also where account_name is 
​"in the friends list of logged in user"

​How can i add the query to pull sth like that? Please check query bellow:

```
 ​$sql = "SELECT p.*, u.avater FROM posts AS p 
    LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.username = p.author 
    WHERE (p.account_name='$u') OR (p.account_name = '(if exist in logged_user friends list')  
    ORDER BY p.postdate DESC LIMIT 20";
```

Comment: How are friends defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to accomplish this would be to use `IN` and then select a subquery in your `WHERE` statement, see below.

I'm not sure of your table structure in `logged_user`, but simply select one column (`id`, in the example below) and then use the `$u` user in the `WHERE` statement.

Note, it's bad practice to include the '$u' directly in the query, and you should be using prepared statements.

```
SELECT p.*, u.avater 
FROM posts AS p 
LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.username = p.author
WHERE p.account_name = '$u'
OR p.account_name IN (SELECT user2 FROM friends WHERE user1 = '$u')
ORDER BY p.postdate DESC LIMIT 20
```

Comment: What's the structure of your logged_users table?

Comment: thanks, but it didnt work, pls check the qus again

i have a friends table with fields (id, user1, user2, accepted)
i want to select posts from the posts table where p.account_name is logged_in user ($u) OR is in $u friends list
(query to select $u friends goes SELECT user2 from friends WHERE user1 = "$u" OR SELECT user1 FROM friends WHERE user2 = "$u"...

pls use the $u variable, am using Prepare statements, if i can get work, i can den use Prepare statements instead

Thanks

Comment: logged_user is a variable
$u = $_SESSION['username'];

Comment: I updated the answer per your notes.  If that doesn't work, apologies I must not understand the question.